# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>'

Tags: dart, flutter

In Dartlang/Flutter, I'm trying to create a List of Maps using `.map()` and `.toList()` but getting the above error message.  I tried adding type annotations in various places, but they just caused similar but different type errors.

Here is the response body.

```
 Response body: {"data":{"logsread":[{"id":"7a2dd3b","email":"email@gmail.com"}]}}
```

And here is the code.

```
http.post(url, body: read2).then((response) {
  print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
  print("Response body: ${response.body}");
  var tempTodos;
  tempTodos = jsonDecode(response.body)['data']['logsread']
      .map((node) => {
            'id': 0,
            'title': node['email'],
            'score': 0,
          })
      .toList();

  return Upd(model.copyWith(todoList: tempTodos));
```

Model class is defined as follows:

```
class Model {
  final String todo;
  final List<String> todos;
  final Map todoWithScore;
  final List<Map> todoList;

  Model(this.todo, this.todos, this.todoWithScore, this.todoList);

  Model copyWith({
    String todo,
    List<String> todos,
    Map todoWithScore,
    List<Map> todoList,
  }) =>
      Model(
        todo ?? this.todo,
        todos ?? this.todos,
        todoWithScore ?? this.todoWithScore,
        todoList ?? this.todoList,
      );
}
```

Comment: I am able to run your map and toList code successfully. I guess the problem lies with your model class. Can you share your model class structure.

Comment: Added the model class definition. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try after adding " as List" as shown below.

```
tempTodos = (jsonDecode(response.body)['data']['logsread'] as List )
      .map((node) => {
            'id': 0,
            'title': node['email'],
            'score': 0,
          })
      .toList();
```